# Reopen request: Isn't “dummy” in “HTML Parser for Dummies” considered offensive?

Tags: support, closed-questions

This is a request to reopen the question, "[Isn't “dummy” in “HTML Parser for Dummies” considered offensive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93187/isnt-dummy-in-html-parser-for-dummies-considered-offensive)" I believe that it is a perfectly legitimate question and not general reference.

(I've also updated the title of the question to better reflect what @UniMouS is asking.)

Answer (score -2):

It has been closed as general reference because the question asks, "Does it mean stupid person? If it does, isn't it too offensive to use like that?" The meaning of *dummy* can be found in a dictionary, and that is the reason for closing the question as general reference.

Apart that, IMO, EL&U is not the place to ask if a word is offensive, in the same way it is not the place to ask about etiquette, or any other social conventions.